# MsSqlServer Regular Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following REGEX: `[I,F,N,B,H,K,V,Y,E,M,P,IS,IU,PP][0-9]{3,8}`

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM *table* 
WHERE Description LIKE '%[I,F,N,B,H,K,V,Y,E,M,P,IS,IU,PP][0-9]{3,8}%'
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions.

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't make sense.  You have defined a character class with duplicates.  Perhaps you should explain what you want to do.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want one of those strings as prefixes.  That is, you really intend:

```
(I|F|N|B|H|K|V|Y|E|M|P|IS|IU|PP)[0-9]{3,8}
```

If so, the "3" is important.  But the "8" is not -- because "8" matches "3".

With that in mind, you can do:

```
where description like '%[IFNBHKVYEMP][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
      description like '%I[SU][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
      description like '%PP[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Strictly speaking, the last condition is not necessary because it matches the first.